# Find similar connected neighbours of a selected cell to form a cluster

Tags: c#, c, algorithm, search

I'm new here and this might be a repitition of a previous post but I couldn't find something specific to this. I have a 2d grid containing of random 4 values (0, 1, 2, 3). I want to build an algorithm which finds all the connected neighbours of one particularly selected cell (can be passed by just giving the index of one cell) and highlight them.

For ex:

I have a 2d array:

[0 0 1 0 3 2 0]

[1 3 1 2 **1** 0 0]

[3 2 3 1 1 1 2]

[0 0 1 2 2 1 0]

[3 2 1 2 1 1 0]

if for example the user selects number 1 (the element highlighted in bold above) i want to find out the cluster that it belongs to and highlight that. Search only for top, bottom, left and right, no diagonals.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you expect actual code from a question, you should limit it to one programming language, choose between c# and c. What are you coding in?

Comment: actually the language isn't really a constraint. in either would work. I right now am working on C#

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for the [connected component](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)) of a [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)#Undirected_graph), which can be found by [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search). Basically you would recursively add all neighbours of the starting node to the output; the details would depend on the specific underlying implementation.

Comment: Good answer. I would personally say that breadth-first search looks more natural on 2D plane and I would go for it, but this is just my opinion :)

Comment: Hi Thanks Codor! I found these articles and i decided I want to build something to implement depth first. now most of the algorithms I found online are either specific codes for a specific unrelated problem or too theoretical using maths and all. Would someone be able to give me maybe just a few steps in plain english on what all the algorithm should do stepwise to get the result? I can convert that into code myself. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can Implement the BFS using a queue and a Boolean Array as follows:

```
 void BFS(int srcR, int srcC, int n, int m, int** grid, bool* vis){
     int dr[] = {1, -1, 0, 0};    //The change in row
     int dc[] = {0, 0, 1, -1};    //The change in column
     int target = grid[srcR][srcC];
     memset(vis, 0, sizeof vis);
     queue<pair<int, int> > q;
     q.push({srcR, srcC});
     vis[srcR][srcC]=1;
     while(!q.empty()){
        int ur = q.front().first, uc = q.front().second;
        q.pop();
        for(int k= 0 ; k < 4 ; ++k){     //The 4 directions we are going to traverse.
            int vr = ur + dr[k], vc = uc + dc[k];
            if(vr>=0 && vr<n && vc>=0 && vc<m && grid[vr][vc] == target && !vis[vr][vc]){
                  vis[vr][vc]=1;
                  q.push({vr, vc});
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

When this function finishes you'll have the `vis` array with ones denoting the connected component.

I'm sorry if there's any error, as I wrote this from the phone.